# Sending Multiple Values With Intent

Tags: android, android-intent

When I try to send more than one value with `Intent`, on target activity only last value is visible. How I can send multiple key,values with `Intent`?

MainActivity.java

```
intent.putExtra(SITE_NAME, site_name);
intent.putExtra(SITE_ADDRESS, site_adress);
```

AnotherActivity.java

```
site_name    =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_ADDRESS);
site_address =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_NAME);
```

When I change the order of `putExtras` last `putExtra` is avaible.

Comment: Your code is fine, are you sure that `SITE_NAME` and `SITE_ADDRESS` have different values?

Comment: yes I sure. Sıte name is like Google site adress like www.google.com

Comment: Or maybe you are doing something wrong when you try to read the extra values.

Comment: Can you post your code?

Comment: Then most likely you are not reading the data correctly from the `Intent`.

Answer (score 0):

You posted this:

```
site_name    =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_ADDRESS);
site_address =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_NAME);
```

I believe you meant this, they're backwards:

```
site_name    =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_NAME);
site_address =  intent.getStringExtra(MainActivity.SITE_ADDRESS);
```

Comment: they are not equal. Only last putExtra is working for me